# How to typeset the formatted counter in compactenum (paralist)?

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate, counters, paralist

I am using the `compactenum` environment from the `paralist` package, and would like to know how I can typeset the counter.

What I mean is

```
\begin{compactenum}[a)]
\item I would like to typeset "a)" here.
\end{compactenum}
```

I was trying to read through the documentation but couldn't figure out which macro stores the counter.

Also, in this case, I don't want to build a reference, because I am only asking for the item label inside that item, i.e., when that counter is at that particular value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\labelenumi` (resp. `\labelenumii`, ..., `\labelenumiv` for nested environments).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{compactenum}[a)]
\item I would like to typeset ``\labelenumi'' here.
\end{compactenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]